# Authentication and Authorization to redirect users to specific pod

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, acl, basic-authentication, kong

Someone knows if does kong has a route based on user-identity (`KongConsumer`) similar to this one in istio?

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity .

I have the service deployed in my K8s cluster using Kong-ingress-controller and some basic-auth plugin

This is the URL domain https://my-application.org/ 
And work with Authentication/Authorization Plugins, this means, work with  ACL and groups.

I want to implement the following
So, when `an user x` enter to the  https://my-application.org/  URL domain, this user will be redirected to `a service x`  which has only the pod deployment to specific customer named `A customer`

And If an  `user y` arrive, this will be redirected to `a service z` which has only the pod deployment to `B customer`

Is this possible to be implemented in KONG?

Comment: Yes  , check their [Oauth2 Introspection plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2-introspection/) which is available with Enterprise offering or there are third party plugins like [this](https://github.com/mogui/kong-external-oauth) which can probably help you achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @fatcook Have you used [Kong External Oauth](https://github.com/mogui/kong-external-oauth), I mean can you give some orientation in relation to how to create the tokens to compose the request, what are the documentation parameters, and also if this plugin have continuous work or is maintained, because looks like from two years ago nobody has performed changes.

Comment: @fatcook Why is necessary the use of  OAuth2.0 protocol? Do I need to think in enables a third-party application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service? I mean why is necessary to implement OAuth2 protocol ...  I am not sure if the basic-auth could give me this functionality?

Comment: @fatcook, I mean could the `KongConsumers` and his/its respective `KongCredentials` which I already created via `basic-auth` plugins should be redirected or authorized to specific pod services without the need to create `paths` based routing in the ingress?